# Unable to resolve host "www.64.media.tumblr.com": No address associated with hostname Android

Tags: android, pagination

i dont know why but after adding pagination in my recylerview this wierd kind of error start displaying i searched for the solutions but didnt get it

and also i have already given the internet permission in manifest

Error 1 `E/libEGL: call to OpenGL ES API with no current context (logged once per thread)`

Error 2 `E/ImageLoader: Unable to resolve host "www.64.media.tumblr.com": No address associated with hostname`

**Short Code // after adding this pagination method im getting the above error**

```
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    int visibleThreshold = 1;
    ContentLoadingProgressBar contentLoadingProgressBar;
    private boolean isLoading = false;


contentLoadingProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.contentLoadingProgressBar);
 final StaggeredGridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) postRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = Objects.requireNonNull(linearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
                int lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    getData();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });

public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }
```

**Entire Code // i have given the entire file code**

```
public class Profile_Fragment extends Fragment implements PostAdapter.OnItemClickListener {
    public static List<Upload> mUploads;
    private final DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
    private final boolean loading = true;
    PostAdapter postsAdapter;
    ShimmerFrameLayout shimmerFrameLayout;
    RecyclerView postRecyclerView;
    Button editProfileButton;
    CircleImageView profilePhoto;
    int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;
    int visibleThreshold = 1;
    ContentLoadingProgressBar contentLoadingProgressBar;
    private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
    private ValueEventListener databaseEventListener;
    private boolean isLoading = false;

    @SuppressLint("SourceLockedOrientationActivity")
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        requireActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        ImageView accountSettings = view.findViewById(R.id.account_Settings);
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.snipet_profile);
        profilePhoto = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.circleImageView);
        editProfileButton = relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_button);
        contentLoadingProgressBar = view.findViewById(R.id.contentLoadingProgressBar);
        editProfileButton.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Fragment edit_profile = new Edit_Profile();
            assert getFragmentManager() != null;
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, edit_profile);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
        });
        accountSettings.setOnClickListener(
                v -> {
                    BottomSheet bottomSheet = new BottomSheet();
                    bottomSheet.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), bottomSheet.getTag());
                }
        );
        postRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.postRecyclerViewProfile);
        shimmerFrameLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmerEffect);
        postRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(
                new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)
        );
        final StaggeredGridLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = (StaggeredGridLayoutManager) postRecyclerView.getLayoutManager();
        postRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int[] lastVisibleItemPositions = Objects.requireNonNull(linearLayoutManager).findLastVisibleItemPositions(null);
                int lastVisibleItem = getLastVisibleItem(lastVisibleItemPositions);
                int totalItemCount = linearLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                if (!isLoading && totalItemCount <= (lastVisibleItem + visibleThreshold)) {
                    getData();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.startShimmer();
                    isLoading = true;
                }
            }
        });
        initImageLoader();
        setProfileImage();
        mUploads = new ArrayList<>();
        postsAdapter = new PostAdapter(getContext(), mUploads);
        postRecyclerView.setAdapter(postsAdapter);
        postsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(Profile_Fragment.this);
        return view;
    }

    public int getLastVisibleItem(int[] lastVisibleItemPositions) {
        int maxSize = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < lastVisibleItemPositions.length; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            } else if (lastVisibleItemPositions[i] > maxSize) {
                maxSize = lastVisibleItemPositions[i];
            }
        }
        return maxSize;
    }

    private void initImageLoader() {
        UniversalImageLoader universalImageLoader = new UniversalImageLoader(getContext());
        ImageLoader.getInstance().init(universalImageLoader.getConfig());
    }

    private void setProfileImage() {
        String imgUrl = "www.64.media.tumblr.com/1276b4edef49034af70bda14325385e3/d8872c747cafa206-96/s500x750/aa915fc49a84b5295f0cd44145d655b66eb906a6.jpg";
        UniversalImageLoader.setImage(imgUrl, profilePhoto, null, "https://");
    }

    private void getData() {
        contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        databaseEventListener = databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    postRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    shimmerFrameLayout.stopShimmer();
                    shimmerFrameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    contentLoadingProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    mUploads.clear();
                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Upload upload = dataSnapshot.getValue(Upload.class);
                        Objects.requireNonNull(upload).setmKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
                        mUploads.add(upload);


                    }

                }

                //notify the adapter
                postsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(int position) {
        Upload selectedItem = mUploads.get(position);
        String selectedKey = selectedItem.getmKey();
        StorageReference imageRef = mStorage.getReferenceFromUrl(selectedItem.getmImageUrl());
        imageRef.delete().addOnSuccessListener(aVoid -> {
            databaseReference.child(selectedKey).removeValue();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Post Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        })
                .addOnFailureListener(aVoid -> Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show());


    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

}
```

Comment: Check if the link is working or not. Put the entire address into a browser(along with the page numbers) and check if the link opens or not. Also check your internet connectivity in your device(hope you have given the Internet permission in the Manifest file , if not please do)

Comment: You probably should use a modern library like Glide, Picasso, Coil etc. The error messages are much more self explanatory and it does provide fallback to some default functionality as well among other things

Comment: yes im using glide for the recylerview images ,im using the universalimageloader for the profile image becuase somenone told me that universalimageloader is good for handling one or two images and for setting a defualt image until user uploades its own

Comment: That someone is very very wrong . Glide can do that too, not to mention the default image is a simple vector art(in a lot of cases it is), you can set it to the imageview directly without any library usage